# Angular 1 service not able to use in Angular2

Tags: angularjs

I have a LoginInfoService implemented in ng1.

To use this in hybrid angular application as per documentation i have done the following -

created app module

```
import { NgModule, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    UpgradeModule
],
declarations: [... ],
providers: [
    LoginInfoService,
    { provide: 'LoginInfoService', useFactory: (i: any) =>     i.get('LoginInfoService'), deps: ['$injector'] },
],
entryComponents:[... ]

})
export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() { /* this is a placeholder to stop the boostrapper from     complaining */
}
}
```

2. created a wrapper ng2 service as below -

   ```
   import {Injectable, Inject} from "@angular/core";

   @Injectable()
   export class LoginInfoService {

       constructor( @Inject("LoginInfoService") public loginInfoService:   LoginInfoService) {
       return loginInfoService;
   }
   isDirectvInFocus() {
       return this.loginInfoService.isDirectvInFocus();

   }
   isWirelessInFocus() {
       return this.loginInfoService.isWirelessInFocus();

   }
   getAccountInFocus() {
       return this.loginInfoService.getAccountInFocus();
   }
   getLoginType() {
       return this.loginInfoService.getLoginType();
   }
   ```

   }

in main ts

```
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['myApp']);//this is angular1 module
});
```

And getting the following error -

```
zone.js:405 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for LoginInfoService! ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for LoginInfoService!
 :-1: 2
```